# Combine two arrays based off of ID and Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays. arr1 has a questionID property, I need to combine arr1 with arr2 based off of arr1 questionID == arr2 INDEX.

so if arr1 questionID = 1 it will match up with arr2 index 1

Is this possible?

Here is what I have so far but this appears to only be combining both arrays based off of their index

```
this.combinedArray = [this.content, this.studyQuestions].reduce((a, b) => a.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, c, b[i])))
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that every item in arr1 has corresponding item in arr2?

Comment: @MoshFeu no, there could be scenarios where arr2 has more or less than arr1

Comment: @MoshFeu arr1 is constant but arr2 changes depending on user input

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can map `arr1` into a new array. The map callback takes the whole item from `arr1` - `...item` and take the whole item from `arr2` in the index given by `questionID` - `...arr2[item.questionID`.

And this is how it works to gather

```js
const arr1 = [{
  questionID: 0,
  prop: 'value1.1'
}, {
  questionID: 2,
  prop: 'value1.2'
}]

const arr2 = [{
    prop1: 'value2.1'
  },
  {
    prop1: 'value2.2'
  },
  {
    prop1: 'value2.3'
  }
];

const combinedArray = arr1.map((item, index) => ({
  ...item,
  ...arr2[item.questionID]
}));

console.log(combinedArray);
```